# URL redirection event handler

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, node.js, dojo

Im in the process of creating a website where http reverse proxy is used to get around cross domain issues. Im think of using php curl or nodejs.  For example http://my-proxyserver-example.com/www.yahoo.com  would load www.yahoo.com into a DIV and there should be no cross domain issues in doing so, because all traffic is going via www.my-proxyserver-example.com

However if i do a search query using www.yahoo.com and see the results and I click on one of the links will results in a url not containing my proxy server address. Is there anyway a url request can be caught through some event handler and the proxy address inserted into the front of the url

I know that I could set up a proxy via the browser setting but this involves users setting up there web browsers to do this and id rather not take this solution. Could nodejs do this service before the web page is received ???

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: All the images, external scripts, stylesheets etc are still coming directly from yahoo, or its content providers.

Comment: When I click on a link provided by yahoo I need to have some way the url link provided to be automaticlly updated so it reads like http// www.my-proxyserver-example/( url link provided by yahoo)

Comment: You can't reasonably and legally do this.  Find another way around the cross-domain problems.

Comment: |I'm not sure how you can say this, if I just set up my browser to permanently go through a proxy server the same thing would be happening.

Comment: You would have to parse all the html, javascript, obfuscated javascript, css, etc and change all the urls to your own server.  You would have to handle any AJAX requests sent to yahoo.  That is why it's not reasonable to do this.

Comment: When you put it like that I sure understand what you mean. Some of this could be done but obfuscated code ....Not possible by any practical means or more. Looks like the cross domain security has won again. The reason why I want to do this are actually quite benign, I just want access to the DOM so it can be changed by the web user in an interactive method so that semi blind or colour blind people can view web pages in a easier manner

Comment: Perhaps a custom-built bookmarklet would be suitable.  Check out [this site](https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/zap.html)